# Проблема загрузки сайта на мобильном после установки JavaScript

Tags: javascript, битрикс, битрикс24

Здравствуйте, столкнулась с такой проблемой. Разместила на сайте такой скрипт. И все хорошо после установки этого скрипта, но проблема при загрузке страницы вскрылась на мобильном телефоне - страница полностью не загружается.
Как можно с этим справиться?

```
<script data-skip-moving="true">
    (function(w,d,u,b){
            s=d.createElement('script');r=1*new Date();s.async=1;  s.src=u+'?'+r;
            h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
    })(window,document,'https://cdn.bitrix24.ru/button.js');
</script>
```

Comment: Ответ при загрузке этого js: `404 Not Found
nginx/1.10.1`

Comment: я название файла изменила, привела пример скрипта,чтобы просто было понятно что он из себя представляет

Comment: Есть вероятность, что тот файл, который вы загружаете, ведет себе по разному на компьютере и мобильном отсюда и проблема с загрузкой.

Comment: этот скрипт сформирован Битрикс24, он для обратной связи с пользователем на сайте. И,если я правильно все понимаю, то он должен одинаково себя вести на любых устройствах. По крайней мере никаких подобных особенностей в описании данной функции обозначено не было